# how to know the default properties' values of UI controller in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

how to know the default properties' values of UI controller in iOS?
Such as an alert view, I have Cancel/OK button on it, how could I know the Cancel/OK button's border color, border width, border's shadow?
And others, like button on navigation bar...

Comment: I'm lost here in guessing, why do you need it?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",alertViewName); but some property you can not get :(

Comment: @iPatel As far as I'm concerned it won't give you the "OK" button border colour, how do you think?

Comment: @SergiusGee - check my edited comment , i know that :)

Comment: You can't get the properties access for alert view as iPatel and Sergius already mentioned. But for Button on navigation bar you can get out its name and selector which is going to be called.

Comment: aha, I'm not good at design, so I want to know some UI controllers' default properties' value, then I could just change it for other similiar controller

Comment: Most of the properties are readonly. Can you please elaborate what specifically you are looking now. So I can give you a to the point reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up everything that's been said here - you can't get most of the data you need for the standard UI elements in iOS. You can however `NSLog` any of the UI elements and check out some of its properties. Be mindful of the fact that about 99% of the system UI elements have `read-only` properties meaning you can't change their look and feel directly (and honestly, you shouldn't).

Check out interesting projects like [UI7Kit](https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit) that allow you to port iOS 7 design to earlier iOS versions. Also [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) are highly recommended for any UI customisation tweaks.